# magento 2.1 throws error in custom module when adding drop down in admin form

Tags: magento2, adminform

I created a custom module in `magento2` for admin panel. Grid form is version fine. But When I tried to add/edit a record then its throwing the error like "**Changes have been made to this section that has not been saved. This tab contains invalid data. Please resolve this before saving.**"

also getting error in log file :

> main.INFO: Item Magento_Backend::system_currency was removed [] []

Comment: This is wrong error. Try to comment 1 by 1 field & check

Comment: Look at page’s source code(ctr+u). In my case, error displayed there.